# Xcode 8.3.3 - How can I make 2 rows in a label?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

So basically, I have created a speedometer but right now I have it outputting "30km/h" on one line.

[image: 1 line label]

What I want it to look like is have 30 on one line and km/h below it.

[image: Like this one]

And if anyone knows how to make that thicker line that goes up the faster you go, that would be a great help.

Here is what my code looks like right now:

```
let speed = (location.speed*3.6)
let speedInt: Int = Int(speed)


//statusLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
//statusLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
//statusLabel.clipsToBounds = true


let statusLabel = UILabel()
let size:CGFloat = 70.0
statusLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
statusLabel.textAlignment = .center
statusLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13.0)
statusLabel.frame = CGRect(x : 172.0,y : 580.0,width : size, height :  size)
statusLabel.layer.cornerRadius = size / 2
statusLabel.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
statusLabel.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
statusLabel.layer.borderColor = UIColor.init(colorLiteralRed: 14.0/255, green: 122.0/255, blue: 254.0/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor

statusLabel.text = "\(speedInt) km/h"
```

Comment: Solutions: Use two `UILabel` or a `NSAttributedString` if you want different size/font/color for each line. If not why not using `\n` between the speed and the units?

Comment: I think that the "84" and the "km/h" labels have different fonts. So in the storyboard, make simply two labels. If you set the constraints correctly ou will have what you are looking for. By doing this, you can use only `speedInt` with no need of concatenation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `UILabel`'s `attributedText` property in order to achieve this look.

Use `\n` to insert a new line to the label.

```
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraphStyle.alignment = .center

let bigAttr = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white,
               NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 60, weight: UIFontWeightLight),
               NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle]
let smallAttr = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12, weight: UIFontWeightLight)]



let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "\(speedInt)", attributes: bigAttr)
attributedString.append(NSAttributedString(string: "\nkm/h", attributes: smallAttr))

statusLabel.attributedText = attributedString
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a \n where you want to split the string. "30 \n kmh"
Or simply add two labels.

Comment: This should be in comment

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add 2 lines in label with the help of UI. Just take a look at below snap[image]

as shown above you can set the line break by word wrapping and simply add the title whole you want. in your case 0 km/h.

Then put the cursor at k and press ctrl + Enter. The title will appears in two lines.